# How to center and change the length of underline?

Tags: html, css, underline

I have text that needs to be underlined only under the middle part of the word.

I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74zgg81d/) and I want the underline should be centered as shown in this [image](https://postimg.org/image/ah52xryjj/).

The CSS code which I have included in the fiddle are:

```
.footer p
{
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f51c40;
}
```

Comment: Is the `::after` pseudo element available for this?

Comment: Please include all relevant code **in the question itself, not on an external site** as an [mcve].

Comment: Why are your footer paragraphs set to `50%` width?  I feel like there's more that we need to see to determine a good solution.

Comment: Also, how much of the middle should be underlined?  Is it half of the word itself, or is it set to a fixed width of `3em` or thereabouts?

Comment: @Mr Lister I haven't used :: after pseudo element in that code. I am not sure how to use that. Can you give me little bit pointer.

Comment: @JosephMarikle  Right, Ok I have reduce the width but still I am not able to centered it. Here is the updated fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/74zgg81d/

Comment: Did you save it?  Also, @MrLister has the right idea.  He should post it as an answer.  This is my stab at that idea: https://jsfiddle.net/3ko0uawv/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an absolutely positioned pseudo element with `left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%);` to automatically center it horizontally relative to the content.

```css
.footer p {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.footer p:after {
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -.5em;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <p>ADDITIONAL INFO</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the ::after pseudo element. if you dont know what pseudo elemts are i recommend you [learn about them here](https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/) since its a very important part of CSS you will use often. the ::after pseudo element is able to add content after a certain element.

you can create a border after the p element for example:

`.footer p::after {content:""; height: 1px; width: 50px; background-color: red;}`

Comment: @MrLister thanks for pointing that out, my mistake. ive corrected my response with the proper wording.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done several ways and more info is needed from you...

Here is one way off the top of my head which is extremely straight forward

```
<div class="footer">
    <p>Add<u>ition</u>al</p>
</div>
```

Another alternative would include using the `.footer p` `:before` and/or `:after` psuedo elements...

Answer (score 0):

It should work like you need

```
footer p
{
  width: 50%;
}

footer p:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 2px #000 solid;
  position: absolute;
  top:40px;
  left: 30px;
  width:100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/74zgg81d/1/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this to use the css pseudo elements `::after`. Also you have to set `display: inline-block` and `position: relative` to the `p` element.

Please see the below snippet:

```css
.footer p {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.footer p::after {
  content: "";
  width: 60px;
  height: 3px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <p>ADDITIONAL INFO</p>
</div>
```